# How to interrupt Galen Framework layout checking?

Tags: layout, frameworks, interrupt, galen

I'm using Galen Framework for Web layout checking in my projects.
The problem is that I have a large amount of HTMl objects and layout rules defined in Galen specification, and somehow at runtime some of them are not discoverable.
It causes Galen run very slow to complete the test.

How can we cancel/interrupt the test while it's still running?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Terminal / Command Prompt to run the test then

> Ctrl + C (Cmd + C in mac) is the standard way to terminate a process
>   on the fly.